# How can I rotate the arrow in 3D world?

Tags: math, rotation

[image]

I'm making an arrow shooting program. As I move forward, I'm going to make it rotate with a look vector as it gradually falls down. However, I don't know if my exploration ability is insufficient or if I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: You multiply your vector by a rotation matrix.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: Consider removing the [c] and [c++] tags :-)